# Feedback on my Javascript search engine project. Prints not all accepting result, no errors displayd

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, string-matching

[JSON data recipes][1]

```js
'use strict';

const cakeRecipes = require("./cake-recipes.json");
console.log(cakeRecipes[0]);


// If you're ready to test: uncomment the code below.
// printRecipes(searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, {})); // 162
// printRecipes(searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, { ingredients: ["carrot"] })); // 3
// printRecipes(searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, { authors: ["Good food"] })); // 32
// printRecipes(searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, { searchTerms: "christmas simple" })); // 5
// printRecipes(
//     searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, {
//         ingredients: ["nuts"],
//         searchTerms: "christmas simple",
//     })
// ); // 2
// printRecipes(
//     searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, {
//         authors: ["best", "cook"],
//         ingredients: ["syrup"],
//         searchTerms: "brunch pancakes",
//     })
// ); // 2


  //***********part 1: declare function search recipes****//                                                                                           
//Use the JSON.stringify method in this function converting the arrays to a string. This by every part of searching to make it possible to search.
const search = [''];
const result = [''];  
function compareArraysWithJSONStringify (arraySearch, arrayResult) {
  return JSON.stringify(arraySearch) === JSON.stringify(arrayResult);
}
let compareWithJSONStringify = compareArraysWithJSONStringify (search, result);
//Create a function called searchRecipes that takes all recipes and an object with search criteria.//This function should return an array of recipes that match the search parameters.// method filter() to create new array that filter recipes based on parameters. Push method to add a new item. Returns new array.   
//set it to lower case to make it case insensitive
//  Creating a function that returns an array of recipes that match the search parameters. Check first if the element is there in the JSON String. 


const searchRecipes = (search,recipe) => {
const filterResult = [];  // declare empty array.  
function filterItems(search, recipe) {
return search.filter((el) => el.toLowerCase().includes(recipe.toLowerCase().filterResult.push((el))))
}
  };

//************** part 2:ingredients***************//
// First use the JSON.stringify method to convert arrays to string in order to do search matching. 
//set it to lower case to make it case insensitive

const filterIngredients = (recipe, search) => {
  recipe = JSON.stringify(recipe).toLowerCase()
  search = search.map((element) => element.toLowerCase()) 
const filterResult = searchItemInRecipe(search, recipe)// have to start searching 
  const result = compareSearchWithResult(search, filterResult) // compare the searching result
  return result
}


//***************part 3:author***************// 
// First use the JSON.stringify method to convert arrays to string in order to do search matching. 

const searchForAuthor = (recipe, search) => {
  recipe = JSON.stringify(recipe).toLowerCase()
  search = search.map((el) => el.toLowerCase()) 
  let result = false
  if (
    search.filter((el) => {
      if (recipe.includes(el)) {
        result = true
      }
    })
  );
    return result
}
//************part 4: searchterms*********// 
const searchForSearchTerms = (recipe, search) => {
  recipe = recipe.Name.concat(recipe.Description).toLowerCase()
  search = search.toLowerCase() //
  search = search.split(" ")   
  const filterResult = searchItemInRecipe(search, recipe)

  const result = compareSearchWithResult(search, filterResult)
  return result
}





// step for searching result recipes and ingredients
const filterRecipes = (recipes, search) => {
  const result = []
  recipes.forEach((recipe) => {    
    const ingredientsInRecipe = recipe.Ingredients
    const ingrendientsInSearch = search.ingredients
    if (ingrendientsInSearch) {
      if (!searchForIngredients(ingredientsInRecipe, ingrendientsInSearch))
        return
    }

  //search for author. Check if all is controlled works. Create new array for result using method push() , then return result
    const authorFromRecipe = recipe.Author
    const authorsFromSearch = search.authors

    if (authorsFromSearch) {
      if (!searchForAuthor(authorFromRecipe, authorsFromSearch)) return. 
    }
    const searchTerms = search.searchTerms
    if (searchTerms) {
      if (!searchForSearchTerms(recipe, searchTerms)) return
    } 
    result.push(recipe)
  })
  return result
}
// Creating a function that takes an array of recipes
const printRecipes = (foundRecipes) => {
 const amountOfRecipes = recipes.length
  let recipeCount = 1
 console.log(
    `Number of matched recipes are ${foundRecipes}  ` );

//Log the found recipes
  recipes.forEach((recipe) => {
    const name = recipe.Name
    const author = recipe.Author
    const description = recipe.Description
    const ingredients = recipe.Ingredients

// print out a list of recipes, displaying the name, author(s), description
  foundRecipes.forEach((recipe) => {
    console.log(`\nRecipe ${recipeCount++}:`)
console.log(`${name}`)
    console.log(`By: ${author}`)
    console.log("\nAbout this recipe:")
    console.log(description)
    console.log("\nIngredients:\n")
    ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => console.log(` * ${ingredient}`))
    console.log("\n______________________________________________\n");
  });

  })
}
   
//Paramenters that are used in search
const searchParams = {
  authors: ["best", "cook"],
  ingredients: ["syrup"],
  searchTerms: "brunch pancakes",
}
```

`First when controlling parts codes it works, but I got comment that it does not check the entire string. Please some guidelines/ what to do better in writing my codes? First JS project.

Thank you so much!

This is the assigment project task:
// Create a function called searchRecipes that takes all recipes and an object with search criteria.This function should return an array of recipes that match the search parameters.
Create a function called printRecipes that takes an array of recipes.
•   This function prints out the number of recipes it was given
•   It should also neatly print out a list of recipes, displaying the name, author(s), `

Comment: could you plz share you actual code here in SO? not using pictures or outside website links

Comment: this line here is missing 2 closing `))` at the end `return search.filter((el) => el.toLowerCase().includes(recipe.toLowerCase().filterResult.push((el));`

Comment: @ChrisG thank you for your respons:) I have shared my code in SO now.

Comment: I'm going to give you two tips that will speed up your learning and productivity enormously: never write code except in a real text editor/IDE (VScode is good for beginners and arguably even non-beginners) and never write more than ~10 lines of code without running it to verify it works. You could be getting feedback on the order of milliseconds to seconds instead of "ask strangers on the internet and hope they reply before the heat-death of the universe".

Comment: Thank you. I'm following a course and have to use Replit for it. And share Replit-link. I have run it , was working. My first project lost track. SO are indeed strangers. I dont get your way of reaction. I have worked intense on thisproject and have some errors I can't fix , asking for feedback. And see many lines of codes of strangers @JaredSmith

Comment: " I'm following a course and have to use Replit for it" write your code in an editor and copy/paste it into repl.it. "I dont get your reaction" you got in over your head because you tried to write too much at once and without proper tools. We can't fix that for you over and over again. I'm trying to [teach you to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime).

Comment: @JaredSmith quit rude. Over and over again? Nobody did. I have already being using VS. I just explained that course use Replit. You did not teach me anything by your respons in this matter. What is wrong for asking feedback? Who is we are you from SO. I can't share my code

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, and I'm sorry it came across that way. I'm trying to **give you the advice I *wish* somebody gave to me when I was first starting out**.  "What is wrong for asking feedback?" nothing except that it's **way too slow**. You will have errors in your code all the time (we all do), if you have to wait for people on the internet to respond each time you will never get anything done. How is pointing that out rude?

Comment: @JaredSmith it's my first post on SO, after working intens alone. First JS project for me. Tried over and over and reaching out now. As many do on SO , incl. fixing errors.  SO is than not the platform for it.  Sure you have to try to do it by yourself to an extend. Thinking by yourself. But if you tried over and over and you can figure it out. I'm in learing stadium. Anyway your respons is clear. In beginning came accros a bit rude.

Comment: Well I'm glad we got things straightened out. Best of luck to you in your studies!

Comment: Once your code _works_ but you still want feedback for improvements, a good place to post is https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CherryDT thank you for your valuable answer. Total new to me. I will give it a try at codereview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Remove the semi-colon and add two closing parenthesis.

Change the code on line 43 from

`return search.filter((el) => el.toLowerCase().includes(recipe.toLowerCase().filterResult.push((el));`

to

`return search.filter((el) => el.toLowerCase().includes(recipe.toLowerCase().filterResult.push((el))))`